# Consultar los tres ultimos datos guardados en Firebase con Android

Tags: java, android, firebase

Buen dia, estoy realizando una consulta a los tres ultimos datos guardados para porder comparar

```
si el ultimo es menor que el segundo y primer dato guardado entonces realizar accion.
```

los datos los tengo guardados de la siguiente manera 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los datos en rojo son las dosis las que debo llamar las ultimas 3.
Alguien sabe como puedo realizar eso ?

Answer (score 0):

Lo respondi en la otra pregunta que hiciste, la estructura de esos datos no es la correcta para trabajar con realtime, estas complicando mucho cuando lo podrias estructurar mejor.

Pero si lo queres hacer asi solo pone limitToLast(3) en la referencia y obtene con getValue() esos 3 , y luego vas a tener que usar algun separator que te tome solamente la primer parte hasta dosis:numero

Lo ideal seria que bajo esa push crees un map con todos tus valores, te dejo un ejemplo

```
Map<String,Object> infoDosis = new HashMap<>();
infoDosis.put("dosis",60);
infoDosis.put("Fecha",tufecha);
infoDosis.put("Hora y ubicacion",horayubicacion);
mDatabase.child("dosis").push().updateChildren(infoDosis);
```

De esa forma el output en firebase va a ser el siguiente

```
dosis
  |__Jks29N2PkshgXz6
  |     |_dosis: 60
  |     |_Fecha: tufecha
  |     |_Hora y Ubicacion: tusdatos
  |
  |_OtroPushKey y la misma data estructurada que arriba
   .....
```

Con eso te aseguras que pones bajo cada push key 3 datos, la dosis, la fecha y la hora, luego con `limitToLast(3)` solo traes los ultimos 3 push key y ahi si podes comparar y obtener solo dosis de cada uno.

Doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data?hl=es-419